# grandchild component doesn't recognize the global state react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hello everyone and thank you for reading,

I'm new to redux and Iv been trying to connect a grandchild component with the store, but for some reason It doesn't work.

The child component (called canvas) uses the store as well and doesn't show any problem, but when I'm trying to get the same data in a component I call from within the child component I get: "Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider tag"

I searched for the solution on the internet and everybody suggests to wrap the app component in provider tags inside index.js, but I already did that in the beginning

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import allReducer from './reducers'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
const store = createStore(allReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());




ReactDOM.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>,
  //</React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import { Canvas } from "./components/Canvas";


export default function App() {
 
  return (
    
    <div className="main-div">
     
        <Canvas/>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

**relevant data from canvas.js (child component)**

```
import { Stage, Layer, Rect  } from 'react-konva';
.
.
.
.
const theTextObjs = TextObjs.map((text,key) => {
    
    return (
      

      <TextBox
        //some irrelevant props
      /> 
       {/* some irrelevant info and other components . . . */}
   
  )});
.
.
.
.

return(
 <Stage
           
            width={ window.innerWidth * 2}
            height={ window.innerHeight * 2}
            //style={{ border: '1px solid grey' }}
            ref={stageRef}
           
            
           
          
          >
            <Layer>
              <Rect
              x = {0}
              y= {0}
              width={ window.innerWidth * 2}
              height={ window.innerHeight * 2}
              fill={"white"}
              stroke={"white"}
              strokeWidth={5}
             
              />
             
              {theTextObjs}
              

            </Layer>
          </Stage>
//some more components
)
```

**inside of TextBox.js (grandchild component)**

```
import React from "react";


import { useSelector} from 'react-redux';


export function TextBox({textEditVisible, textX,fill,textY,textValue,fontSize,width,height,fontStyle,align,id,onDragStart,isSelected,onClick,onChangeEnd,onContextMenu,onChangeEdit,onClickedit,onKeyDownEdit,event}) {

  const selectedTextObj = useSelector(state => state.selectedTextObj)
  const TextObjs = useSelector(state => state.TextObjs)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
 //
 //some irrelevant info
 // ...
  
  return (
      <>
            {/* more irrelevant info */}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where do you use the `theTextObjs` variable? Is it returned as part of the return value of the `Canvas` component?

Comment: Also what is `const TextObjs = useSelector(state => state.TextObjs)`? Are you storing a React component in the Redux store?

Comment: yes, its returned as part of the return value of the Canvas component

Comment: I store an array of objects and each object contains information I use as props for each TextBox component I render

Comment: Are you calling `TextBox` as a function anywhere, rather than using it in JSX? Otherwise I can't see anything wrong with your code, sorry. Maybe you can try to make a minimal example in a code sandbox or similar?

Comment: I think I have the same suspicion as Guillaume, that the code with `TextObjs.map` is running somewhere outside of the react rendering context. We'd need to see some more context from that component to see what's going on.

Comment: Nope, I don't. it also happens with every other  grandchild component. thanks for trying tho, appreciated.

Comment: ill have another look timotgl.

Comment: actually I return it from with in a layer of a stage (konva library). Didn't think that it might be the issue. ill look into it now, thanks anyways!(PS I added the return part of the Canvas component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a different React renderer such as Konva, you need to wrap the components within the different Renderer within a new provider. In the case of Konva, the children of Stage.

See [this issue](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/issues/188).

```js
const store = useStore()

return ( <Stage
           
            width={ window.innerWidth * 2}
            height={ window.innerHeight * 2}
            //style={{ border: '1px solid grey' }}
            ref={stageRef}
           
            
           
          
          >
           <Provider store={store}>
            <Layer>
              <Rect
              x = {0}
              y= {0}
              width={ window.innerWidth * 2}
              height={ window.innerHeight * 2}
              fill={"white"}
              stroke={"white"}
              strokeWidth={5}
             
              />
             
              {theTextObjs}
              

            </Layer>
           </Provider>
          </Stage>
```